# Python Selenium: Send Keys to CVV Box

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a 'CVV' number field and enter numbers into it. I am trying the following code:

```
ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cvNumber"]'))).click()
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cvNumber"]').send_keys('0000')
```

However I get error

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the HTML from where I want to select:

```
<div class="ncss-container text-color-grey prl0-sm mt2-sm mb2-sm" id="j_c219" data-juno-component="view/forms/creditCardIframeForm/creditCardIframeForm" data-juno-name="creditCardIframeForm"><iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe mt1 u-full-width" src="https://paymentcc.nike.com/services/cvv?id=86ac6e90-bf6b-4762-bf2d-d0bc960a37e7&amp;t=AMERICANEXPRESS&amp;lf=2009" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>

<form id="creditCardForm" method="post">


    <div class="cvv-container ncss-row mb4-sm prl2-sm">
      <div class="ncss-col-sm-12 prl0-sm u-va-t border-light-grey u-rounded">
        <div class="ncss-row">
          <label for="cvNumber" class="ncss-col-sm-8 text-color-grey pt2-sm pl6-sm pr2-sm pb2-sm u-va-m americanexpress-icn-launch">
            0000
          </label>
          <div class="ncss-col-sm-4 u-va-m">
            <div class="cc-container ncss-input-container error">
              <input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="1" data-shortname="cvv" class="cc-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm u-align-center" "cvv"="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="" maxlength="4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <input type="hidden" id="parentDomain" value="https://www.nike.com">
    <input type="hidden" id="enableIFrameBuster" value="true">

  </form>
```

The form looks like this:
[image: The red box is where I want to enter details]

Comment: Generally CVV fields are placed within a frame. Check for iframe tag.

Comment: @DebanjanB updated the post with more html, how would i go about with the iframe

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium with Python documentation UnOfficial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Hii there

Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

this will work for you

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('cvNumber').send_keys('0000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally *CVV* fields are placed within an `<frame>` or in a *Modal Dialog Box*. Irrespective of that as per the *HTML* you have shared to *Send Keys to CVV Box* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='cc-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm u-align-center' and @id='cvNumber']"))).send_keys('0000')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, it is still not working. How would I switch to the frame first?

Comment: I have shared the iframe HTML in the original post, does that help?